# Change - to _ in file names

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

I have files named this way

```
A-1
B-3
C-5
U-8
A-2
```

... and so on.

I want to change the name of all these files to this because the software I want to use didn't accept files named that way and I think it's because of `-`.

```
A_1
B_3
C_5
U_8
A_2
```

So basically I just want to change `-`  by `_` in all the files, using for loop or something.

Answer (score 1):

this command should work for you

```
for FILE in *; do NFILE=$(echo "$FILE" | sed s/-/_/g);  mv "$FILE" "$NFILE"; done
```

The forloop grabs all the files in the directory, you could add something like `*.png` to filter the files. In this loop the filename is echoed and piped to sed. Sed is a handy tool which can do all sorts of things, but we use it to change the `-` to a `_` by the syntax: `s/find/replace/g`. After this we use this new variable to move the existing file to the new name a.k.a. renaming it.

Let me know if you need any more help!

Edit:
As Shawn mentioned below, if you are using bash or zsh you can use the building function and don't need sed. This command would look like this:

```
for FILE in *; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE//-/_}"; done
```

Really nice and compact, Thanks Shawn!

Comment: You can also use the parameter expansion `${FILE//-/_}` to change the dashes to underscores if using bash or zsh (But not sh), so `mv "$FILE" "${FILE//-/_}"`